# split the string with space , starts with paranthesis using javascript

Tags: javascript

Can someone help with below ,

I have a string with

var str = "func(1,2) and func(3,4) and (func(5,6) and func(7,8))";

How we can achieve below outputs for above string?

[func(1,2), and, func(3,4), and , (func(5,6) and func(7,8))]

[func(1,2), func(3,4), func(5,6), func(7,8)]

Comment: All those nested double quotes make your code both incorrect and difficult to understand. Consider editing it so it is valid javascript.

Comment: @Mark python? lol

Comment: Doh... thanks @epascarello...not enough coffee yet.

Comment: unsure your output because the way it is written it is nested...

Comment: @Mark, I have edited my question. Can you help with possible ways?

Comment: When asking your question, please format your code as code using the markdown available to you to do so.  Your question is unclear.  It sounds like you want to parse a string respecting nesting of parentheses (unclear what other syntax may or may not apply) and split that string into fields.  It's unclear what the rules are for formulating the second output example.  What do you want to do with unbalanced parentheses?

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for ?

```js
var str = "func(1,2) and func(3,4) and (func(5,6) and func(7,8))";
var result = str.replaceAll("and ", "").split(" ")
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: An attempt to answer i'd say, but as I was not sure having understood the question very well...

Comment: Thanks, but input string won't have  same  string "and"  between func. sometimes, it can have combination of "and", "or".

Comment: Well then `str.replaceAll("and ", "").replaceAll("or ", "") ... etc`